# How to clean rails console output when using pry-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pry

I have in my Gemfile pry-rails gem. I would like to use pry as rails console but without that text below.

How to clean my rails console output, now I receive a lot of unnecessary text:

```
>> Subscription.where(user_id: User.last.id)
  User Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x7f7f9ad69c70
  @implicit_readonly = nil,
  @join_dependency = nil,
  @order_clause = nil,
  @records = [],
  @should_eager_load = nil,
  attr_accessor :bind_values = [],
  attr_accessor :create_with_value = {},
 ...
```

https://gist.github.com/4025796

Comment: What do you mean, "mess"? This is pry, pretty-printing a return value.

Comment: I guess you have the `pry-rails` gem installed. Remove it, and just use the `pry` gem, it should not override the default rails console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [second Pry tip](https://twitter.com/pryrepl/status/255080531228778496) you can use semicolon in the end of your expression.

```
>> Subscription.where(user_id: User.last.id);
>>
```